# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm fine tuning bert model for ner task and in the evaluation step after tarining I get this error

```
from seqeval.metrics import accuracy_score

def flat_accuracy(preds, labels):
    flat_preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=2)
    flat_labels = labels
    return accuracy_score(flat_preds, flat_labels)
```

```
from seqeval.metrics import f1_score
from seqeval.metrics import accuracy_score
def flat_accuracy(preds, labels):
    flat_preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=2).flatten()
    flat_labels = labels.flatten()
    return np.sum(flat_preds == flat_labels)/len(flat_labels)
```

```
def valid(model, testing_loader, dev):
    model.eval()
    eval_loss = 0; eval_accuracy = 0
    n_correct = 0; n_wrong = 0; total = 0
    predictions , true_labels = [], []
    nb_eval_steps, nb_eval_examples = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for _, data in enumerate(testing_loader, 0):
            
            for k, v in data.items():
                data[k] = v.to(device, dtype = torch.long)
 
            ids = data['ids']
            mask = data['mask']
            targets = data['target_tags']

            output = model(**data)
            loss, logits = output[:2]
            logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
            label_ids = targets.to('cpu').numpy()
            predictions.extend([list(p) for p in np.argmax(logits, axis=2)])
            true_labels.append(label_ids)
            accuracy = flat_accuracy(logits, label_ids)
            eval_loss += loss.mean().item()
            eval_accuracy += accuracy
            nb_eval_examples += ids.size(0)
            nb_eval_steps += 1
        eval_loss = eval_loss/nb_eval_steps
        print("Validation loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
        print("Validation Accuracy: {}".format(eval_accuracy/nb_eval_steps))
        
    return flat_accuracy
```

```
#tags_vals = list(set(df_data[""].values))
predictions, true_labels = valid(model, valid_data_loader, device)
```

the error I get is TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object
does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: You're returning `flat_accuracy` from `valid`, and `flat_accuracy` is a function. Did you intend to call that function and return its result, or to return something else? (I suspect that you want `return predictions, true_labels` instead.)

Comment: you are right I missed predictions, true_labels it works now thanks.